# Can't get Meteor app deployed on Ubuntu (Nginx issue)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, meteor, ionic-framework

I can't get meteor app deployed on my VPS (It's new VPS with fresh Ubuntu installation).

I followed well this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx#step-1-%E2%80%94-setting-up-an-nginx-web-server

From A to Z.

But when i test my application i get:

```
502 Bad Gateway.
```

I check status of:

```
service nginx status
status mongodb
```

It's ok, but:

```
status myapp
```

Return: `myapp stop/waiting`

Checked the logs:

```
/home/myapp/myapp.log
```

There nothing.

Same as mongodb logs.

But found this on nginx logs:

```
2018/03/02 01:08:19 [error] 2651#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: 185.12.85.65, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "185.12.85.65"
2018/03/02 02:57:11 [error] 2653#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: 185.12.85.65, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "185.12.85.65"
2018/03/02 12:52:16 [error] 2655#0: *25 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: 185.12.85.65, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "185.12.85.65"
```

Nginx location:

```
# pass all requests to Meteor
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    #proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

    # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
    # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
    # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
    if ($uri != '/') {
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

I noticied that port 3000 not opened.

```
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/mongod
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      784/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6578/nginx
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/mongod
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6578/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      784/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6578/nginx
```

Any one encountred this problem before ? Any fix please ?

Comment: Can you show your anonymized nginx location config of the app?

Comment: Please can you explaign me more ? What do you mean by that ? Do you mean this location: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp` ?

Comment: Something described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) and [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure)

Comment: @Jankapunkt i updated the post with your request :)

Comment: Why did you change the `proxy_pass` ?

Comment: Because i tried it throue 8080 with no success, i tried with 3000 and didn't worked too.

Comment: I changed it too inside `/etc/init/myapp`

Comment: check the log specified in the upstart conf `/home/todos/todos.log`

Comment: @FredStark Log return nothing, i already did that !

Comment: Sorry I missed that in your post. Try taking the executable contents of the startup script (inside the `script` block) and running that from the terminal. See if the app starts, or if it gives you a readable error?

Comment: Hi I followed the same setup for several apps. the only time I get that error is when the meteor app is not running for any reason. If you run `curl localhost:3000` does it give you a html page? If so your app is running and not sure what to do. If it says something like connection refused then look at why not. I would cd to the bundle directory and run `node main.js` and check for errors in the terminal.

Comment: You can use http://meteor-up.com/ for meteor deployments

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor Up](http://meteor-up.com/docs.html) ([Source Code](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up)) can replace step 4 in your Tutorial and when you need to redeploy just run `mup deploy` instead of step 5. They even provide SSL support.